# Is this Proof by Induction a backwards proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

let $P(n)$ be the statement that $1*1!+2*2!+...+n*n! = (n+1)! -1$

P(1) is true because 
$1*1! = (1+1)! - 1 = 1$

Assume $P(n)$. Shall show that $P(n+1)$ holds.

$1*1!+2*2!+...+n*n! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)! - 1
\\(n+1)! -1 + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)! -1  
\\(n+1)! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)!
\\(n+1)! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(n+2)
\\n+2=n+2$

Was this ok, or should I have started with the LHS and manipulated the LHS only so that eventually it equaled the RHS, (n+2)! - 1.

Comment: Yep, this is not a proof. You're assuming what you want to prove (unless you show that all your manipulations are if and only ifs).

Comment: You have shown "if $P(n+1)$ then $n+2=n+2$". Well, "if $2=3$, then $n+2=n+2$" is also a true statement... it doesn't really say anything. What you need to show is "if $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$".

Comment: Thanks all. Yep, should have manipulated the LHS only toward $= (n+2)! -1$

Comment: I very much dislike these "let's meet in the middle" calculations and if I had my way they'd be banned from the universe.  But **IF** every step of the way is equivalent (follows if and only if) and **IF** the prover states so (you didn't) then it is a valid proof.  And each step of your proof follows if and only if the previous one does.  So your proof would have been valid if you had stated the each step was an iff manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof would have been valid if you had stated

$1*1!+2*2!+...+n*n! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)! - 1 \iff
\\(n+1)! -1 + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)! -1 \iff  
\\(n+1)! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+2)! \iff
\\(n+1)! + (n+1)(n+1)! = (n+1)!(n+2) \iff
\\n+2=n+2$

(Although, aesthetically I *hate* those type of "meet in the middle" proofs.  Although they can be handy for proving inequalities.)

Your proof, as it stands now,  reads as though you are stating what is to be proven as a fact and you are attempting to prove the conclusion "n+2 = n+2".

Each step of a "meet in the middle" proof has to be equivalent (if and only if) to the previous.  If any are only one way it is invalid.

$5 = -1
\\5 - 2 = -1 - 2
\\(5-2)^2 = (-1-2)^2
\\25 - 20 + 4 = 1 + 4 + 4
\\25 - 20 = 1 + 4
\\25 - 1 - 20 = 1-1 +4
\\24 - 20 = 4
\\20 - 20 =  0
\\20 = 20  $

is, of course, invalid.  The error would be obvious if this were a direct "proof".